# Rails 3.2 :remote => true, Bind to After Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form field that I would like to empty immediately the submit.  Usually I would do something like:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(/* custom craft request */);
  $("#field").val('');
});
```

Rails handles all the custom crafting when I add the `:remote => true`, but I can't find a way to bind to immediately after the submission.

The documentation ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html ) insists there's an ajax:after event, but that doesn't seem to exist.  Apparently this documentation is completely outdated, since other functions like remote_form_for don't exist in 3.2

Any help is appreciated.  The setTimeout I'm using really doesn't sit well.

EDIT: Adding the working setTimeout solution that I want to replace:

```
$("#form_id").submit(function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        //this will happen after submission     
    }, 15);
});
```

Comment: FWIW the list of supported events is in https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax. It doesn't have an 'after'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach to ajax callbacks by doing this:

```
$("#form").bind("ajax:send", function(e){
   $("#field").val('');
});
```

Don't forget to include the rails.js library https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: This isn't firing.  I also don't see anything in rails.js that would cause it to fire.  Does anyone have it working in Rails 3.2?

Comment: `ajax:after` seems to have been removed. Try `ajax:send`.

Comment: By the way, I tried this with `ajax:send` in rails 3.2.8 and it worked fine.

Comment: Yup, it was ajax:send.  I see it now in the source https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js - right after submitting the form with `var jqxhr = rails.ajax(options);` they call `element.trigger('ajax:send', jqxhr)`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the ujs wiki (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax), all ajax global events are available: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

So this should do the trick:

```
$("#form").bind("ajaxSend", function(){
  $("#field").val('');
});
```

I'm assuming you want the event triggered immediately as the request is sent. Otherwise you can of course use the following to clear the field upon completion (works for failure or success):

```
$("#form").bind("ajax:complete", function(){
  $("#field").val('');
});
```

Comment: ajaxSend is an interesting idea.  Unfortunately it's a global event and not a local event, so it pertains to all ajax requests rather than just the ajax request for the specific form.  As a result, it may cause problems if there are other AJAX requests running on the page.

The issue with ajax:complete is that it doesn't happen until the request is complete and the server has returned content to the javascript.  This means it's not ideal for things like preventing duplicate submissions.